# What version of node.js is embedded with Omnis Studio 10.2 31315

Tags: node.js, omnis-studio-10

The Omnis docs state "node.js is embedded into Omnis Studio".

I understand I can check node.js version in terminal `node -v`, however this is the version on my machine itself.

How do I determine what version of node.js is bundled within Omnis Studio?

Answer (score 2):

After installing it, you can go to the directory that contains Omnis' Node executable. On Windows, it may be:

```
C:\Program Files\Omnis Software\OS 10.2 31315\clientserver\server\remotedebug
```

Then you can run `node -v` from that directory. The latest version looks to be 16.6.1. (This may well be a different version from the global Node on your personal machine - for example, my global Node version is 14, which I get when running `node -v` elsewhere, outside of that directory)

The latest [release notes](https://omnis.net/developers/resources/download/manuals/Whatsnew102.pdf) also say that the Node version in Macs is also 16.6.1:

> The version of Node.js released with the macOS version of Studio 10.2 is now V16.6.1
> which supports node running natively on macOS on M1 machines.

Comment: Great. On the mac side I found "node" in /Applications/Omnis\ Studio\ 10.2\ 31315.app/Contents/Resources/remotedebug/node . However, I had to drop it into terminal which then gave me the version number - v16.6.1.